# How to create weather format UI in HTML

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using open weather API to display the weather data, but I am not able to create a format like below.

Example output:
[image: example image]

I have tried to display like this:

```
       <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-md-3'> 
             <p> wed </p>
             <p> ... </p>
          </div>
          <div class='col-md-3'> 
             <p> Thur </p>
             <p> ... </p>
          </div>
       </div>
```

but it is coming one after one instead of next to each other on mobile screens how can I achieve this.

Comment: please include whats your problem, effort, making it

Answer (score 0):

You can create this using css grid. hope it will solve your problem.

```css
h5 {
  color: grey;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.grid-content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7 , minmax(32px, 1fr));
  gap: 2px;
  place-content: center;
}
.grid-content div {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ddd;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h5>Daily</h5>
<div class="grid-content">
  <div>
    <h5>MOn</h5>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h5>Tue</h5>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h5>Wed</h5>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h5>MOn</h5>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h5>THR</h5>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h5>FRI</h5>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h5>SAT</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```